# Force process switch using a semaphore to measure cost of process switch

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, semaphore, binary-semaphore

I am trying to measure the cost of a process switch, and to do that I am trying to use a semaphore. I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it. Can somebody help me with an algorithm or with ideas?
Right now I fork, and have two if statements, one for if the pid==0 and one for pid>0. I am going to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC to get clock measurements, but I am not sure what to do with the semaphore itself.

Comment: Some code would help to understand what threading functions, and semaphore functions, and timing functions you're using. Also, you should add a tag for the actual operating system that you're using.

Comment: Using a semaphore to measure the cost of a process switch will probably not give you very accurate results.  I would say, just measure the performance of a process running alone as A, measure the performance of two identical processes running in parallel as B and C, and see what is the difference between A and (B+C).